# Angular HttpClient - how to handle both string response and Error (json) response?

Tags: angular, rest, http, httpclient

I have a Java endpoint that returns a STRING response body in case of success (something like "user created successfully") or an `ErrorResponse` object (JSON) in case of error.

How would you tackle this issue from the perspective of Angular HTTP Client? (I'm using Angular 10). For example, if I use `{responseType: 'text'}` for the string response, in case I get an error from the back-end, my JSON object will be a string and I don't want that. I found a workaround with `JSON.parse()`, but I don't like this approach at all...

Please see below my method:

```
  public register(user: User): Observable<string | ErrorResponse> {
    return this.http.post(
      "someUrl",
      user,
      {responseType: 'text'})
      .pipe(catchError((errorResponse) => {
      if (!errorResponse) {
        return throwError({
          message: "An unexpected error occurred!",
          timestamp: new Date()
        } as ErrorResponse);
      } else {
        const err = JSON.parse(errorResponse);
        return throwError(err);
      }
    }))
  }
```

I appreciate every opinion.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if using `{ observe: 'response' }`can help or not:https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response

Comment: I tried that before, but I'm receiving an `Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:8080....` on success (text response)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `HttpErrorResponse` instead of `ErrorResponse`. `HttpErrorRespose` has a property caleed "message" which should contain the server message

Comment: I'm using HttpErrorResponse in the HttpInterceptor and rethrowing an ErrorResponse (custom class).